# SSL config Apache 2.2.3

Tags: apache, сервер, ssl, apache2, hosts

Заказали сертификат SSL, пускай тут будет на *example.com*, нам его видали все ок, настроил для десктопа норм, но потом еще узнал что использується m.example.com, где, что и как нужно настроить?
Смотрю пока в ssl.conf

```
<VirtualHost m.example.com:443>
    ServerName m.example.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2

    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile pathTo/example.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile pathTo/example.com.key

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
               AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
               SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
               "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует несколько видов сертификатов. Если совсем не уходить в подробности они подраздляются на три вида:

1. сертификат на 1 домен
2. сертификат на несколько доменов
3. сертификат на неограниченное количество поддоменов (так называемый asterisk-сертификат, или "звёздочка"-сертификат

Вам необходимо у вашего продавца сертификатов уточнить можно ли "обновить" Ваш сертификат до одного из вариантов: 2 или 3. Второй вариант более безопасный, так как в случае кражи секретного ключа злоумышленник не сможет подделывать произвольный поддомен.

Что касается настроек - то посмотрите пример который предоставляет Mozilla: https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

Comment: Спасибо, покупал на GoDaddy